# Questions about recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I was helping a friend with some CS work he was having trouble with, when we ran into a question about recursion. I wrote the code to test it out myself but I still don't quite understand what it's doing. Can anyone explain?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sum(int a, int b)
{
if (a == b)
    return 0;
else
    return a + sum(a + 1, b);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", sum(3, 7));
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Does this mystery friend do your homework on Sundays as well?

Comment: @EdHeal Too much HW tonight :)

Comment: @EdHeal sorry about the answer. Just did mechanically, and didn't read the plot of the question ((( I agree with you, totally.

Comment: so you are helping a friend with his homework and you dont even understand the piece of code you wrote?

Comment: This question [has already been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26962234/596781).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sum(a,b) is computing the sum of all integers between a and b-1 (inclusive). That is, sum(3,7) = 3+4+5+6

**EDIT**: why it is so? Because when you call the function with arguments a and b, you can decompose the call as follows:

```
sum(a, b)
a + sum(a+1, b)
a + (a+1) + sum(a+2, b)
a + (a+1) + (a+2) + ... + sum(b,b)
```

and in that case, since sum(b, b) returns 0, you can (intuitively) see that the function sums all the numbers from a up to b-1. I hope it helped more constructively now.

Comment: Please do not do homework for others - end up with programmers that do not do their job

Comment: @EdHeal, so no one has ever helped you with anything? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: @Novaea he should ask the prof/ta for help, they will know the right amount of help to give, not the direct answer

Comment: @Steve, I wanted to know. He's asking the prof tomorrow. I wanted to learn for my own benefit. God forbid.

Comment: There is a difference between help and giving an answer. Giving an answer does not teach anything

Comment: @EdHeal, I don't give him answers. I explain things to him when he needs help.

Comment: I think it's a good moment to stop loosing time with this, guys.

Comment: sum(3,7) = 3+4+5+6 - Is that not the answer>

Comment: @EdHeal It's a waste of time really. Whenever you try to educate someone about some noble principles, you will need to go through some pain and even take the blame and be seen as "evil". This is by design. That's why I gave up since if you ever convinced someone, there will be 10 others that pop out from nowhere to destroy our noble cause. I guess closing and moving on is the sane thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Initialy we have:
    sum(3,4)
Then: 
    3+sum(4,7), 
    3+4+sum(5,7), 
    3+4+5+sum(6,7), 
And finaly:
    3+4+5+6+sum(7,7).

sum(7,7) is 0 so result is: 
    18.